# Trouble installing Ubuntu 12.10 alongside windows 7

Tags: wubi, windows-7, laptop

I have a windows 7 laptop. I downloaded the Wubi.exe from ubuntu and whatnot, and ran it. After all that went well, I rebooted to finish the install.Then  I get a screen that says
" Try (hd0, 0): NTFS5: No wubildr
  Try (hd0, 1): NTFS5:             "
Nothing else... if I let it sit for five or ten minutes it just stays there. What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to workaround this, but one might argue that the whole point of Wubi - to try out Ubuntu easily from Windows and easily uninstall - is lost when you have to employ workarounds to get it to boot.

The workaround is to copy the `wubildr` file to the first partition of your computer `/dev/sda1`. There are various ways to do this e.g. from an Ubuntu live CD/USB, or by assigning a drive letter to the partition in Windows (it's likely your boot partition with no mapping), and then copying it from `C:\` to the newly mapped drive.

My advice would be to try Ubuntu from a live USB and then if you like it, just do a normal dual boot. Unless it's really important not to modify partitions.

PS if you want some background on `wubildr` and `wubildr.mbr` you can read this: [wubildr, wubildr.mbr and grldr](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/01/wubildr-wubildrmbr-and-grldr.html)